# Sort comma separated values of column

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I am having a column `'ids'` with comma-separated values and I want to sort it while selecting records.

```
--------------------
Name | ids | value |
--------------------
A    | 1,2 | 10    |
A    | 2,1 | 20    |
--------------------
```

Expected Output

---

```
Name | ids | value |
--------------------
A    | 1,2 | 10    |
A    | 1,2 | 20    |
--------------------
```

Comment: Show the query you've tried, and what was wrong / unexpected with the result.

Comment: Using comma-separated values in a column is almost always a bad database design decision. Normalizing that data is almost always the appropriate choice.